# Conditional constraint in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a way to do this `add_index :issue_types, [:name], :unique => true` if only there is no uniqueness true?

like `add_index :column, [:name], :unique => true if !:unique`

I have 100s of tables where i need to find where there is no uniqueness and make it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check your **schema.rb** file.

When you see something like this:

```
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
```

You are sure that column in this case 'email' is already unique. So you can target other columns for migrations.